# Using a Wordpress Page Template to Reduce the Amount of Html Needed to Edit the Page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, templates, content-management-system

I'm designing a website in WordPress (as a CMS) for my company to help newly hired employees learn about us, but it is ultimately going to be managed by a different department. After seeing the large amount div tags and the like used with the css and jquery to make it look acceptable, it's become apparent that the training document will probably just be an HTML manual. I'm not very good with php, but after reading about custom page templates in WordPress I was wondering if there was a way to use one div tag with a specific meaning in WordPress's HTML editor that would be interpreted by the page template and implement the more complicated HTML tags? Would this even be logical?

Thanks in advance for any help, and I can clarify if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

> a way to use *one tag* with a *specific meaning* in *WordPress's HTML editor* that would be *interpreted* by the page template and implement the *more complicated* HTML tags

[Shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)